# "to save" or "to be saved"

Tags: meaning

I am translating a technical report from Chinese to English regarding the use of a computer program. I want to remind users to store their data in a specific format. Which of the following instructions is correct?

> 1. Be sure that the data to be saved should be in a specific format.
> 2. Be sure that the data to save has to be in a specific format.

Comment: You might want to check out [ell.se], which might be a more appropriate place to ask about future translation questions.

Comment: Could the original perhaps be closer to "be sure that the data is saved in a specific format"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases (including this), the passive infinitive is an alternative to the infinitive phrase in adjectivals / adverbials:

> This is the data to save.
>
> This is the data to be saved.
>
> Is this the pie to eat?
>
> Is this the pie to be eaten?
>
> This is a problem to avoid at all costs.
>
> This is a problem to be avoided at all costs.

BUT not all cases:

> He is the man to ask.
>
> *He is the man to be asked. (different meaning)
>
> What a nice car to drive.
>
> *What a nice car to be driven.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, but neither sentence is entirely correct. Here's my try to rephrase them:

- Ensure that the data to be saved is in the required/requested/specified format.
- Ensure that the data to save is in the required/requested/specified format.

*Be sure* means *you can be certain*, while *ensure* means *check*. If you use *should be* or *has to be* it would mean that the user needs to check **if** the data needs to be in a specific format or not, so you want to use the infinitive here. Also, all data is in a specific format, so I think you mean it has to be in the format you specified.

Comment: Or: _Ensure the data is in the required format before saving it._

Comment: @J.R. That's way better, but I wanted to stay true to the question. If I had to choose, I'd choose your option.

Comment: @QOI - I'm pretty sure that, if the O.P. is translating a technical report, the O.P. would be open to (and appreciative of) any improvement – not just wordings that fit the initial phrasings given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence to translate looks incomplete, or at least doesn't fully make sense.

If there is just one correct format for this situation, you can say:

> Ensure you save your data in the XYZ format.

If the user has to choose a format before saving, a better way to say this would be:

> When saving your data, you must first choose a format.